# How to force app being destroyed while in background for testing

Tags: android

I have a problem in an application that occurs after the application is destroyed while in the background. While I have some fixes in place, I want to be able to test them immediately.

If I background my application and do a "force stop" from system settings on the app, this doesn't seem to recreate the issue when I then resume the app.

Right now, I have to background the application and wait nearly 12 hours before trying it again.

How can I tell android to destroy the application so that I can test my fixes without waiting around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an option in new versions of Android in Settings>Developer Options called Don't Keep activities which will destroy every activity as soon as the user leaves it. Not sure if this does a force stop or not, but worth looking at.

Comment: thanks I tried this actually on a 4.1 phone and forgot about it. I recently nailed this problem down to the tablet ui and hadn't tried this option there, worked perfectly! thanks for bringing this up.

Comment: I've been testing this, however it definitely (on Nexus 5 4.4) does not destroy the app completely. When i close an app, it seems to do something different like even the desktop refreshes as if its stopped, but when i re-enter my app objects such as the bundle are still read. Is this right? Surely the bundle would be wiped also right? I must be missing something...